# Alternates to iHub for cloud based reporting

Tags: birt, reportserver

Shortly before Open Text acquired Actuate I stood up an iHub F-Type server on Amazon so that people in my little company could have access to reports and information.  Now that the acquision is completed Open Text has discontinued support and availability for F-Type and is directing users like me to full blown iHub which they make available free for 45 days (which they will, so they say, extend to 90 days) and afterwards it is a paid service and not affordable for me.

My question is...how are others providing for cloud based reporting for users in a way that is affordable?  I am aware of [this project](https://reportserver.net/en/) that appears to offer something like what F-Type used to.  Has anyone tried this ReportServer?  Any thoughts or experiences you could share?

I am also open to other reporting platforms (Jasper, etc.) if they offer what I am after.  This would be my least preferable option but my users wouldn't really know or care so I could do it if I needed to?

Comment: This is a shopping question which is out of scope here.

Comment: We've been using ReportServer quite successfully, so I guess no harm in trying it out. For more specific questions I'd suggest to go to the official forum http://forum.reportserver.net/.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest BIRT Runtime Release Build (4.5.0), put the engine in a server, add scripts to run the reports you want.

http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/build.php?build=R-R1-4_5_0-201506092134